# For loop with showing key one time in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Does anybody know how to show key only one time not for every time in for-loop in gnuplot?

e.g.

```
filename(n) = sprintf("band%d", n)
plot for [i=0:9] filename(i) using (\$1):(\$2-$vbm1) w l lt 1 lw 3 lc rgb "sienna1"
```

In this case, 100 keys written in `filename(i) using (\$1):(\$2-$vbm1)` are generated for every runs in for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use a conditional explicit title, for example:

```
plot for [i=0:9] filename(i) ... w l t (i==0?'some title':'')
```

this would show the key only for `filename(0)`